# Implicit grant token for Microsoft Graph gets lost on IE / Edge

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, oauth, microsoft-edge, microsoft-graph-api

I have been connecting quite some OData source with our SQL query engine. I am currently working on integrating some Microsoft Cloud solutions using the Microsoft Graph API. I have successfully authenticated and connected to Microsoft Dynamics CRM, which is quite similar to the Graph API.

For our applications we are running the OAuth implicit grant flow to prevent we gain access too long to systems. Usually these tokens are invalid within an hour or so. It is important for us to use this implicit grant for some other security implications too.

I have an issue now when using the implicit grant using Internet Explorer or Edge. It seems that the access token returned from the OAuth endpoint is too long for Microsoft to digest.The tokens I have previously been using were shorter than 2048 characters, but this endpoint returns one of more than 2200 characters.

I am using this OAuth call:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com&scope=openid

When successfully authenticated on Chrome it returns at the redirect URI (`localhost` in the above sample):

> https://localhost/#access_token=eyJ...6yUQ&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3599&session_state=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111

But on IE / Edge it returns as:

> https://localhost/

I do see using the IE Developer Tools that the 302 issued by Microsoft has the correct `Location` header, including the `access_token`. However, since IE/Edge has a limitation on the URL of 2048 characters, the URL gets truncated at the fragment.

Eventually this boils down to an issue we have with the `WebBrowser` control we use in C#, but the problem is bigger.

I had like to have some alternatives I could use to successfully gain an `access_token`. In summary, the requirement is *Be able to receive a very large `access_token` through the URL fragment, or have a way to let MS shorten the `access_token`*.

I have been using CefSharp as alternative browser component, but it has some issues running in AnyCPU mode and the workarounds are broken now. I would love to see a solution that would also work for our web applications, so we don't have to force users not to use IE/Edge.

Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post the access token itself? Or decode it in jwt.io and post the claim contents here? I'd like to see what's making the token so large, this usually isn't a problem.

Comment: This is one advantage of the authorization code flow vs. the implicit flow, and using `response_mode=form_post` as opposed to `fragment` or `query`

Comment: Any resolution on this?

Comment: @lehiester unfortunately not.